# How do I use a String as a Stream in .Net?

Tags: .net

I need to call a method that accepts a stream argument. The method loads text into the stream, which would normally be a file. I'd like to simply populate a string with the contents of the stream, instead of writing it to a file. How do I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a MemoryStream with a StreamReader. Something like:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms))
{
   // pass the memory stream to method
   ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); // added from itsmatt
   string s = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Might want to mention that you'll have to rewind the stream before using it to read from it. :)

Answer (score 5):

Use the StringWriter to act as a stream onto a string:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
CallYourMethodWhichWritesToYourStream(sw);
return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: A StringWriter is a type of TextWriter, not a type of Stream, so it can't be passed to a method that expects a Stream.

Answer (score 2):

Look up MemoryStream class

Answer (score 2):

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
YourFunc(ms);
ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
string mystring = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

is one way to do it.

Comment: Hmm... didn't see Bryant's response earlier - essentially the same thing.  Oh well.  His will work if you add the Seek call to it.

Comment: This code actually works. It would be great to merge this with Bryant's better-formatted response, but I don't have the reputation to do that yet...

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like:

```
string s = "Wahoo!";
int n = 452;

using( Stream stream = new MemoryStream() ) {
  // Write to the stream

  byte[] bytes1 = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s);
  byte[] bytes2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(n);
  stream.Write(bytes1, 0, bytes1.Length);
  stream.Write(bytes2, 0, bytes2.Length);
```

Comment: Or you could just construct the MemoryStream from the bytes1[] array.